# Why is my process running with vshost32.exe instead of vshost.exe on a 64-bit OS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm running a process through the Visual Studio 2015 debugger, with the active solution platform set to "Any CPU", on a 64 bit OS.  When I look at the process in Process Explorer, the Description field is set to vshost32.exe, but if I set the active solution platform to "x64," the Description field shows vshost.exe.

Why would it be selecting vshost32.exe on a 64 bit machine?  I have confirmed that calling "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727>Ldr64.exe query" returns 1, meaning it should prefer 64-bit on a 64-bit machine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the default behavior for a C# project on a 64-bit OS. If you want to make a 64-bit Application, uncheck the "Prefer 32-bit" build setting in your project properties page. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb4wyys2.aspx for more details of project properties.