# Performance difference between AnyCPU vs x64 platform on a 64 bit machine

Tags: c#, performance, clr

According to [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062028/performance-of-a-c-sharp-application-built-on-anycpu-vs-x64-platform-on-a-64-bit) there should be no performance difference between application built using Any CPU and x64 when run on a 64 bit machine, however I'm seeing around a double increase in performance in my use case when I specifically built for the x64 platform.

My use case is for manipulating 64 bit [bitboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitboard), the majority of processing is on bit operations and arithmetic on `ulong` variables.

As an example:

```
public static ulong ReverseBits(ulong x)
{
    ulong t;
    x = (x << 32) | (x >> 32); // Swap register halves.
    x = (x & 0x0001FFFF0001FFFFUL) << 15 | // Rotate left
        (x & 0xFFFE0000FFFE0000UL) >> 17; // 15.
    t = (x ^ (x >> 10)) & 0x003F801F003F801FUL;
    x = (t | (t << 10)) ^ x;
    t = (x ^ (x >> 4)) & 0x0E0384210E038421UL;
    x = (t | (t << 4)) ^ x;
    t = (x ^ (x >> 2)) & 0x2248884222488842UL;
    x = (t | (t << 2)) ^ x;
    return x;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ulong sum = 0;
    var s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (ulong i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        sum += ReverseBits(i);
    }
    s.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Sum = {0}, took {1}ms", sum, s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

In Release build with Any CPU platform the results are:
`Sum = 9745675244420464640, took 13148ms`

In Release build with x64 platform the results are: `Sum = 9745675244420464640, took 5693ms`

That's more than double performance increase. Why is there such a big difference if the common assumption is that Any CPU vs x64 builds should perform the same on a 64 bit machine?

Comment: is that with or without optmize code ?

Comment: I suggest you print out `Environment.Is64BitProcess` just to check that it *really* is running 64 bit code...

Comment: @JonSkeet you hit the nail on the head. Any CPU is running 32bit code. I was under the impression Any CPU will always run 64bit when executed on 64bit machine. Is there a way to force this, or is x64 the way to go?

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438511 is relevant?

Comment: That did the trick, unchecking `Prefer 32-bit` forced 64 bit code, thank you. Do you want to post an answer, or should I delete this question?

Comment: @Beyers Please don't delete your question. In the absence of an answer that solves your problem, you can always post your *own* answer and give credit to those who supplied helpful comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you compared perf between 32-bit and 64-bit code.  The x64 flavor is much faster because it can do the math with a single 64-bit processor register.  It is much more of a slog in 32-bit machine code, it has to juggle two 32-bit registers.  Easy to see the difference between the two with Debug > Windows > Disassembly.

This went wrong because you paid too much attention to the solution platform name.  Too prominently displayed, but a selection that only matters to C++ projects.  And, unfortunately, on UWP projects due to .NET Native.  It selects the build tool flavors, C# has only one compiler that can target any platform.

The *real* settings that matters are the jitter forcing options.  Project > Properties > Build tab.  Select the Release build if necessary and choose the Platform target and "Prefer 32-bit" settings.  Untick the latter.  You'll now see that AnyCPU == x64 on a 64-bit operating system.